# Does anyone know the concept of tables __syncArticles, __syncTransactions, __syncSubscriptions in Sync Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization

Does anyone know the concept of tables created (__syncArticles, __syncTransactions, __syncSubscriptions) by Sync Framework?

Why every one of them?

Thank's!

Comment: Searching I found that these tables are generated by a feature of SQL Server (ChangeTracking)